# JPA @PostPersist How to access HttpServletRequest?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to implement @EntityListener

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
@Data
@EntityListeners(ProfileListener.class)
public class Profile implements Serializable {
...
}
```

and ProfileListener.class I want to access HttpServletRequest for get some data to use inside @PostPersist

```
@PostPersist
public void PostPersist(Object ob) throws IOException {

}
```

**Edit**
I tried to use

1.)  RequestContextHolder

```
@PostPersist
public void PostPersist(Object ob) throws IOException {
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

}
```

and I got error **java.lang.NullPointerException**

2.) ApplicationContext

```
 @PostPersist
    public void PostPersist(Object ob) throws IOException {
    HttpServletRequest  httpServletRequest = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(HttpServletRequest  .class);

    }
```

and I got error **java.lang.NullPointerException**

3.) `@Autowired private HttpServletRequest request;`
AFAIK ProfileListener.class is a class outside of Spring Application Context so I can't use Autowired

Comment: Don't... You really don't want to do that. Don't tie your entities to http.

Comment: Try autowiring `@Autowired private HttpServletRequest request;`

Comment: Try to use RequestContextHolder class in Spring API. You can use it like `HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
            .currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();`

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha => Autowired doesn't work (request = null) . AFAIK ProfileListener.class is a class outside of Spring Application Context so I can't 
use Autowired and I tried to use ApplicationContent to get bean but it doesn't work also

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to write log to Bigquery that the old schema of table required ipaddress

Comment: Probably a bad idea, but you can use some ThreadLocal static container somewhere to set it earlier, then access it from there in the PostPersist method.

Comment: You can use the `RequestContextHolder` to obtain the current request and the information therein. However do you always have a request when updating/inserting entities? If you have some offline process or other means you don't have a request and things will break down.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried to use HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest(); inside PostPersist and I got NullPointerException you can look at my edit.

Comment: Which indicates you aren't running inside a http request or aren't using Spring but something like  Jersey and the request context filter. or listener hasn't been setup.

Comment: OK I got it, I should remove http part from entity listener. Thanks